# How to schedule an Xagent from a Domino Java agent?

Tags: java, xpages

Trying to get an Xagent to run on schedule by triggering from a scheduled Java agent.

The following is the code for my xagentmail.xsp which simply sends me an email:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="false">
 <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
// test send mail
doc = database.createDocument() ;
doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "memo");
doc.replaceItemValue("Subject", " from xagentmail.xsp");
doc.replaceItemValue("SendTo", "PDella-Nebbia@testdomain.com");
doc.send();

}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
</xp:view>
```

Using the SSL-ENCRYPTED connection approach described in Devin Olson's blog,   [Scheduled Xagents](http://www.learningxpages.com/blog.nsf/dx/06252015103949AMDOLK7Y.htm?opendocument), I created the following scheduled Domino Java agent:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
 import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
 import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter; 
 import java.net.Socket; 

 import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory; 

 import lotus.domino.AgentBase; 

 public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase { 
 // Change these settings below to your setup as required. 
 static final String hostName = "server1.testdomain.com"; 
 static final String urlFilepath = "/test/poidemo.nsf/xagentmail.xsp"; 
 static final int sslPort = 443; 


 public void NotesMain() { 
   try { 
     final SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(); 
     final Socket socket = factory.createSocket(JavaAgent.hostName, JavaAgent.sslPort); 

     final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())); 
     final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 

     final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
     sb.append("GET "); 
     sb.append(JavaAgent.urlFilepath); 
     sb.append(" HTTP/1.1\n"); 
     final String command = sb.toString(); 

     sb.setLength(0); 
     sb.append("Host: "); 
     sb.append(JavaAgent.hostName); 
     sb.append("\n\n"); 
     final String hostinfo = sb.toString(); 

     out.write(command); 
     out.write(hostinfo); 
     out.flush(); 

     in.close(); 
     out.close(); 
     socket.close(); 

   } catch (final Exception e) { 
     // YOUR_EXCEPTION_HANDLING_CODE 
   } 
 } 
 }
```

When I enter the URL in a browser to my xagentmail.xsp I get mail as expected.

But my scheduled Java agent is not triggering the Xagent to send the mail.

I did set the Anonymous access to Reader for the application with both the agent and xagent.  I also have restricted and non-restricted privileges on the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: what message do you get when you run the agent through the server console?

Comment: What security level are you running the Agent with (1, 2, 3)?

Comment: Actually running blind right now on a customer dev server.  Console access not an option there.  Need to move to a test server.

Comment: @Eric my id has restricted and non-restricted privileges on the server.  Not sure what level that is

Comment: I'm less concerned with your ID, more wondering what the security tab for the agent shows. [Screen shot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ud08ibj7z6wgemu/Screenshot%202016-03-31%2013.11.28.png). Devin's blog post says it needs at least level 2 (Allow restricted operations) to work.

Comment: @Eric ahhh, I see now ... my agent was at level 1 ... changed to level 2 and see if that gets it moving

Comment: No, moving it up to level 2 did not do the trick

Comment: I'm just having the agent call the xagent on localhost (with proper Internet site in place). The agent doesn't need ssl then. Try that approach instead.

Comment: @PaulDella-Nebbia Nuts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the following approach which works great: I use HttpURLConnection instead of a BufferedWriter and I use localhost on port 80 to talk directly with the server locally.

Here's my agent code:

```java
import lotus.domino.AgentBase;
import lotus.domino.Session;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    @Override
    public void NotesMain() {
        try {
            final String xpageName = "demo";

            Session session = getSession();
            dk.fmcgsolutions.XAgent.run(session.getAgentContext(), xpageName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the XAgent class that the agent uses:

```java
package dk.fmcgsolutions;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import lotus.domino.AgentContext;

public class XAgent {

    public static void run(AgentContext agentContext, String xpageName) {

        try {

            String dbPath = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase().getFilePath();
            String url = "http://localhost/" + dbPath + "/" + xpageName + ".xsp";

            System.out.println("Starting " + xpageName + " in database " + dbPath);

            URL xPageURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) xPageURL.openConnection();

            conn.connect();

            switch (conn.getResponseCode()) {
            case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
                // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Response: " + line);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();

                break;
            case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR:
                System.out.println("Interal server error while running");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("An error occurred: " + conn.getResponseCode());
                System.out.println("Error message: " + conn.getResponseMessage());
                break;
            }

            conn.disconnect();

            System.out.println("Finished " + xpageName + " in database " + dbPath);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The agent needs to run with runtime security level 2.

Comment: This site currently set up via Web Configurations.  Can you also set up a local Internet Site when using Web Configuration?  How do you do that?

Comment: Sure. Just use "localhost" as domain name.

Comment: Thanks Per, I will try that ... need to talk to the admin now!

Comment: Could it be, that the SSL Ciphers on the webserver are too strong for the java agent ?

Comment: @umeli your question is meant for the question and not my answer, I assume.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten yes, to the question above

Comment: Hi @PaulDella-Nebbia. Did you try it out?

Comment: Not yet, but I plan too as soon as I get back into this project

Comment: @PaulDella-Nebbia great to hear!

Comment: One question, the suggestion suggested by you Per to run an XAgent from a scheduled agent only works for Notes databases with anonymous access at least reader. Because I'm testing on a basis where authentication is required and prompts for username and password.

Comment: @MarcusLoza it works with No Access for anonymous. You just need to enable access to read public documents and then mark the XPage as available for public access